# space out date in x axis for plot in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a time series plot in python, it's producing the results i want, except the axis is not quite right...

the figure is below:

[image]

I just want to space it out through the whole plot figure...

my code below :

```
x2 = all_sentiment['date']
x2 = pd.Series(list(set(x2)))
y2 = all_sentiment['sent_count']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(20, 10))
axes.plot(range(len(s_pos)), s_pos, linewidth=2, color='green')
axes.plot(range(len(s_neg)), s_neg, linewidth=2, color='red')
#axes.set_xticks(x2.index.tolist())
axes.set_xticks(np.arange(len(x2.index.tolist())))
axes.set_xticklabels([date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for date in x2])
axes.margins = 0
axes.set_xlabel('Date/Time')
axes.set_ylabel('Num of Tweets')
axes.set_title('Number of Tweets Over Time - Positive and Negative')
axes.set_xlim(0, len(y2))
axes.legend(loc="upper right", labels=['Positive', 'Negative'])
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)
plt.show()
```

Can you point out what I've done wrong here?

thanks much appreciated.

Comment: I would first suggest to remove the lines `axes.set_xlim(0, len(y2))`, `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)`, `axes.margins = 0`. Then update your question.

Comment: I've figured it out, mistake on axes.set_xlim(0, len(y2)) , changed to x2